Can we use angular 18 on Nx 18.2.0
According to the documentation, the latest version of Nx is 18.2.0, which is compatible with Angular 17.3.0. However, there hasn't been a new Nx release specifically for Angular 18 yet.
Is it possible to use Angular 18 with Nx version 18.2.0?


They released version 19.1.0, which includes support for Angular 18. For more details, see here

Yeah seems that they merge the PR but didn't release it. give you upvote

@AlirezaAhmadi Hi, nx 19.1 has been released and should support angular 18. There's also a migration which should upgrade your workspace correctly

@Pieterjan Thanks but still couldn't find it in their official website: https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/documents/angular-nx-version-matrix

You're right. It should still be added here

There is a release out mentioning support. https://github.com/nrwl/nx/releases/tag/19.1.0

@BrianLudaPooe still is not there. check https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/documents/angular-nx-version-matrix

@AlirezaAhmadi its literally there on the link you just sent hey its a region thing cause i can see it.

I just created a new nx app and its on v18

Yes, now it's there and they released it.

This might be a trial an error scenario. As Nx document isn't clearly documented accordingly. You can proceed with the manual updation on your dependencies in your Nx workspace and try it out.
Follow the below steps :
1. Modify package.json accordingly


    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
      "@angular/cli": "^18.0.0",
      "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
      // Add other Angular packages as needed
    }



2. Depending upon your package manager run `npm install` or `yarn install`
3. Adjust Nx Configuration to Ensure that your `Nx` workspace configuration (nx.json and project-specific configurations) aligns with Angular 18's requirements and ecosystem. This might include updating builders, schematics, or other Nx-specific settings. 
4. Next run npm install --legacy-peer-deps
5. Lastly test your application for any flaws

Thank you for your response. However, I'm facing difficulties with the numerous dependencies and their respective versions. This is why I'm seeking an automated update solution rather than a manual one.

Once you go ahead with manual once you can find out which peer dependency libraries needs to replaced / updated accordingly. automated will just give you failed,.. Now I have told all these appreciate if you can mark it as correct answer and give an upvote for it. :-) thanks in advance

I mean I have a big workspace which contains 10 apps and 15 libs so it's not possible to go through it manually. but will give you an upvote and wait for more answer
